# `cleveref` does not work inside a note page (beamer)

Tags: beamer, cleveref

`cleveref` package works well in my beamer frames, but when it comes to note pages. The tags work well and `cleveref` can refer to items outside the note page, but not to items inside it

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}                       
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{Eq. (#1)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

    \begin{block}{Derivation of Equivalent Impedance}

        \begin{description}[<+->]
            \item[Item 1] Item 1
            \item[Item 2] Item 2
                \note<.>{\begin{equation}e = m c^{2}\label{eq}\end{equation}\cref{eq} is what we want.}
            \item[Item 3] Item 3
                \begin{equation}e = m c^{2}\label{eqx}\end{equation}\cref{eqx} is what we want.
        \end{description}

    \end{block}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make an example that is a bit more minimal?

Comment: It is shorter now

Comment: I bet you could reduce the example to less than 20 lines and still reproduce the problem

Comment: Apparently, labels inside a `\note` don't find their way in the `.aux` file. It's not a problem specific with cleveref: also the standard `\ref` (without loading `cleveref`) has the same issue.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it or does this require reimplementation of some low level `cleveref` or `LaTeX` macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround you could place the note outside of the frame:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}
\useoutertheme[]{split}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}

\setbeameroption{show notes}

\setbeamersize{description width=0mm}                       
%\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{equation}{Eq. (#1)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<-2>[label=foo]

    \begin{block}{Derivation of Equivalent Impedance}

        \begin{description}[<+->]
            \item[Item 1] Item 1
            \item[Item 2] Item 2
            \item[Item 3] Item 3
                \begin{equation}e = m c^{2}\label{eqx}\end{equation}\cref{eqx} is what we want.
        \end{description}

    \end{block}\end{frame}

 \note{\begin{equation}e = m c^{2}\label{eq}\end{equation}\cref{eq} is what we want.}

 \againframe<3->{foo}    

\end{document}
```

[image]